# JSON encoded array comes out as null in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, json

I am making a small drag and drop app using jQuery UI's Sortable feature.  The jQuery works fine but when I try to encode the array of all of the lines in their order, the PHP script on the other side reads the array as `NULL` and I cannot figure out why.  Here's everything in the order that they appear in my first script:

The HTML

```
<form method="post" id="reorder" action="orderupdate.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="post_ids" name="post_ids">
    <button type="submit">REORDER</button>
</form>

<ul id="photo-selector">
    <li id="img1"><img src="images/img1.jpg"></li>
    <li id="img2"><img src="images/img2.jpg"></li>
    <li id="img3"><img src="images/img3.jpg"></li>
    <li id="img4"><img src="images/img4.jpg"></li>
    <li id="img5"><img src="images/img5.jpg"></li>
    <li id="img6"><img src="images/img6.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

The JS

```
$(document).ready( function(){

    var formOrder = document.getElementById('reorder');
    formOrder.addEventListener('submit', function(){
        var post_ids_field= document.getElementById('post_ids');
        var ul_id = document.getElementById("photo-selector");
        var post_ids = ul_id.getElementsByTagName("li");
        post_ids_field.value = JSON.stringify(post_ids);
        alert("check");
    });

});
```

When clicking the "REORDER" button in the form up top it sends to `orderupdate.php` which is as follows

```
<?php

    $post_ids = json_decode($_POST['post_ids']);
    var_dump($post_ids);

    require("opendbas3.php");

    foreach ($post_ids as $x => $value) {
        $query = "UPDATE dav_posts SET p_order='$x' WHERE post_id='$value'";
        $result = mysql_query($query, $link);
    }

?>
```

Now when I do submit, it redirects me to the PHP script `orderupdate.php` it doesn't execute the query and I found out that the `foreach` loop cannot read the `$post_ids` array.  I only get `NULL` with my `var_dump()`.  Also, the `alert` in the JS script doesn't fire off on either the `ready()` function or the event listener's submit.  It just redirects to the PHP script.

Is something out of order?  What could be wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call JSON.stringify on DOM elements -- that is the reason the alert never fires.  You'll find it crashes with `TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`.

What you need to do is map the `li` array to an array of strings:

```
var id_strings = [];
for (var i=0 ; i<post_ids.length ; i++) {
    id_strings.push(post_ids[i].getAttribute("id"));
};
post_ids_field.value = JSON.stringify(id_strings);
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RD6vg/10/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
post_ids = $("#photo-selector").sortable( "toArray");
post_ids_field.value = JSON.stringify(post_ids);
```